# Represent JPanel in UML

Tags: java, jpanel, uml

I am asking based on this question

[UML and java classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555057/uml-and-java-classes)

I have a class that extends Jpanel.
A jpanel class must be added to my uml diagram to show "extends".
But the problem is I read a class diagram must have list of methods in it too.
So must I draw a class titled JPanel and list all the methods in JPanel class by reffering to java docs?
Or can I just draw a rectangle with title JPanel only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So must I draw a class titled JPanel and list all the methods in JPanel class by reffering to java docs? Or can I just draw a rectangle with title JPanel only?

Why do you want to draw the diagram?  UML is a language; it doesn't mandate what you can or can't do with it.  It's not mandatory that you list all the methods in JPanel.  Just show what you need for your purposes.  If the only thing you're trying to communicate is that your class extends JPanel, just draw the two classes with the extension relationship.  You don't have to show any attributes or methods if they're not relevant.

hth.

Comment: Unfortunately our teachers reject projects if there are errors in UML diagram. But this makes sense looking at the large list of JPanel methods. Tank you for the answer. :-)

Comment: Then ask them to define 'error'.  I would say an 'error' in a diagram is something that violates the UML metamodel.  That metamodel allows a class to have 0 or more attributes and 0 or more operations.  The spec also allows for class diagrams that show classes without attributes or operations. So - unless they've been more specific about what constitutes an error - then omitting them from the diagram is not an error.  You could always add a comment to explain your rationale. hth.